# Exception handling Try Catch block

Tags: c#-4.0

I have been reading about exceptions for the past couple of hours and have a basic understanding. However the book I'am reading hasn't got the best examples when it comes to showcasing the coding aspects. I know that if I have code that could fail I wrap it in a try block and the catch the exceptions specifically i.e FormatException etc.

However the confusing part is when it comes to call stack were for e.g Method A calls Method B and Method B calls method C etc.

For example a exception occurs in Method c but it doesn't have a catch handler so it propagates back to the calling method so on and so fourth until one way or another the exception is handled.

What I was wondering is does execution continue in the method that caused the error or does execution continue in the method that handles the error.

Any basic examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I was wondering is does execution continue in the method that caused the error or does execution continue in the method that handles the error.

Second one is correct.For example in your `B` method if there is exception thrown and not handled,it goes to the caller method for example `A`,and if `A` handles that exception program will continue execution from that method.Consider this example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     A();
}

static void A()
{
    try
    {
         B();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Exception is thrown by {0} method and handled in A method.",ex.TargetSite);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("We are still in A method...");

}

static void B()
{
    throw new Exception();
    Console.WriteLine("We can't see this...");
}
```

This will produce the output:

```
// Exception is thrown by B() method and handled in A method.
// We are still in A method...
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't repeat what the other answers have already said, but one other thing to point out is that any *finally* blocks will be executed *after* the `catch` statement happens, but *before* the exception is re-thrown down the stack.  In other words, *finally* blocks are executed from the top of the stack, down.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Crash(); // Causes a crash
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Third"); // Exception re-thrown, this runs third
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fourth"); // Run last
    }

    // Code will continue here when all is done
}

static void Crash()
{
    try
    {
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First"); // This runs first
        throw; // Re-throw exception
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second"); // This gets run second
    }

    Console.WriteLine("This will never execute..");
}
```

Will output *First*, then *Second*, *Third*, *Fourth*.